# Did Martin Scorsese lie in Life Itself?

Tags: dialogue, life-itself

In [*Life Itself* (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2382298/), Martin Scorsese says because of Roger Ebert, his life was saved from drugs before *Raging Bull*.

> Martin Scorsese: During the '80s was extremely...I was gone,
>   basically. Broke, and I'd gone through some bad, bad periods. My third
>   marriage had broken up, and I was basically alone. The only thing that
>   saved me or made me want to... continue just like living, in a way,
>   was my agent called this festival up in Toronto." I said, "Yeah."
>   "Roger Ebert, Gene Siskel, ........................(I skipped it). 
>   And I started my life again, you know.

But what actually happened is [Robert De Niro saved Martin Scorsese from drugs](http://thenewdaily.com.au/entertainment/movies/2016/04/30/robert-de-niro-saved-martin-scorseses-life/). So what explains this discrepancy?

Comment: Did you skip the whole comment or just edit it down? It's not clear what it is Ebert & Siskel did or didn't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [Signature-Reads](http://www.signature-reads.com/2011/02/martin-scorsese-on-raging-bull-robert-de-niro-movies-and-more/):

> MARTIN SCORSESE: The only good thing about the drug use is that it was
>   very obvious in my case. And I just had to go to that brick wall.
>   Nobody was going to tell me otherwise, whether it was a rock 'n'
>   roller, or a studio executive, or an actor. People can try to guide
>   me, but I always have to go my own way.
>
> RS: The only reason I bring it up is because it's part of the public
>   record of your life.
>
> MS: Right. After "New York, New York" I was exhausted to the point
>   where a number of people were worried about my health. I said, "Don't
>   worry, I'm fine." And then after the Labor Day weekend in Telluride,
>   at the film festival, I got back to New York and suffered a total
>   collapse. That's when I finally went to the hospital, and that's when
>   De Niro came to visit and asked if I wanted to do the film. Really, we
>   had been working on it since Taxi Driver. I realized I had nothing
>   else to do. I had exhausted all the possibilities. Even my friends
>   were all going off on their own. I was alone. And it was time to go
>   back to work. And what I discovered - it's in "Raging Bull" and it's
>   in the other pictures later on - is that I had to come to terms with
>   something.

So, it seems Scorsese saved his own life, but DiNero had a hand in it.  Or, possibly a conversation with Ebert at that film festival caused the initial collapse.  Tough to tell.